# why is exterior of the microwave oven getting hot & the lights getting switched off

Tags: equipment, pizza, microwave

cooking pizza @ 180 degrees celcius then the exterior gets too hot and the lights on the microwave oven get switched off. after it cools down the lights start again

`

Comment: You probably have a broken microwave. Take it to a repair shop or consult with a technician. I don't think this question will survive here, some other SE site may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The exterior is getting hot because it is generating a lot of heat.  A pizza has a bit of mass and 180 degrees Celsius is hot.  It could be a safety shut off.

And it could be broken.

If it works fine with smaller items then more likely it is a safety shut off.